# Inconsistent Runtime error '1004' - Delete method of range class failed

Tags: vba, excel

I have written some VBA in excel to iterate a relatively large set of data in order to perform some basic formatting and tidying up. The code previously worked and still works when I use a break point and step through it. However, when i don't step through it and just let the code run by itself, the spreadsheet becomes unresponsive. Once I've pressed escape a few times I get the runtime 1004 error (see title) and the relevant line is hightlighted.

I'd like to reiterate that when i set a break point on the offending line and step through it, it works fine and the row is deleted as appropriate. Also when I test the syntax in a much smaller data set it works perfectly so this is not syntax related.

Any help will be greatly appreciated because I'm stumped. Here is the code:

```
Private Sub CommandButton21_Click()

Dim index As Integer, lapsedSchemes As New Collection, lapseDates As New 
Collection
Dim iRow As Long
Dim iCol As Integer

Sheet1.Columns(5).NumberFormat = "dd-mmm-yy"                   
Sheet1.Columns(14).NumberFormat = "dd-mmm-yy"                   

iRow = 2

Do While Sheet3.Cells(iRow, 1).Value <> ""                      

    lapsedSchemes.Add Sheet3.Cells(iRow, 1).Value
    lapseDates.Add Sheet3.Cells(iRow, 2).Value
    iRow = iRow + 1

Loop

iRow = 2

Do While Cells(iRow, 7).Value <> ""                            

    index = 1

    If Cells(iRow, 9).Value = "" Then                           
        If Cells(iRow, 7).Value = Cells(iRow, 8).Value Then
           Cells(iRow, 9).Value = "Policy Holder"
        Else
           Cells(iRow, 9).Value = "Dependant"
        End If
    End If

    For Each scheme In lapsedSchemes                                                    

        If Cells(iRow, 4).Value = scheme And Cells(iRow, 5) = lapseDates(index) Then  
            Cells(iRow, 4).EntireRow.Delete                                            
            iRow = iRow - 1
            Exit For
        End If

        index = index + 1

    Next scheme

    iRow = iRow + 1

Loop

appendLegacyData (iRow)
Range("A1:AZ10000").Sort Key1:=Range("A1"), Order1:=xlAscending, Key2:=Range("D1"), Order2:=xlAscending, Key3:=Range("E1"), Order3:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes

End Sub
```

The offending line is:

```
Cells(iRow, 4).EntireRow.Delete
```

The sheet becomes unresponsive and only when I press escape a few times does the runtime error show.

Comment: what's the value of `iRow` at error. `Cells(0, 4).EntireRow.Delete` will throw 1004.

Comment: 5511 which is the first line the IF statement is true for. There are c122k rows in total

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unresponsive doesn't mean that Excel crashed. Deleting rows one by one is just painfully slow.

You can use

```
application.statusbar=cstr(iRow)
DoEvents
```

to see your progress and keep Excel responsive.

If it will work to slow, I recommend you to set some value in rows to delete, sort by that value and then delete them all together.

Comment: But the code ran fine previously. Plus, even though there are c122k rows in total, there are probably only about 100 that need deleting. I have let this run for about 10 minutes without it responding.

Comment: I will try your suggestion though where do I need to paste your code?

Comment: in main loop. statusbar is that text in bottom left corner. DoEvents refreshes Whole Excel.

Comment: Yes you are correct, the code is running but it is painfully slow!!!It runs fine until it hits the first row to be deleted and then it never really recovers, just runs slow for the rest of the run time. I will take your advice and just mark each row to be deleted and then sort and delete them at the end. Thx bro.

Comment: probably there is some bug in deleting rows/columns, but it is hard to isolate it. good luck.